# fsolve error in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, nonlinear-functions

I am dealing with the following code:

```
function opemployment=eqns(unknown);
global kappa varphi lgamma beta r delta s x b e theta v;
h=unknown(1);
gamma=unknown(2);
opemployment(1)=(h^(gamma-1))*((1-kappa)*((lgamma*(varphi^beta))/(gamma*kappa*beta+1-kappa))*h^(gamma*beta-gamma)-(r+delta+s)*(s^(gamma-1))*x^(-gamma));
opemployment(2)=(1-kappa)*(b-e+(kappa/(1-kappa))*theta*v^(gamma-1));
```

and then call:

```
close all; clear all;
global kappa varphi lgamma beta r delta s x b e theta v;
kappa = 0.1;
varphi = 2;
lgamma = 3;
beta = 0.9;
r = 2;
delta = 2 ;
s = 3;
x = 5;
b = 4;
e =3;
theta = 3 ;
v = 2;
guess = [0.7,0.3];
sol=fsolve('eqns',guess)
```

Yet, I receive the following error: 
    'Error using feval
       Undefined function 'eqns' for input arguments of type 'double'.

```
Error in fsolve (line 217)
        fuser = feval(funfcn{3},x,varargin{:});
```

Caused by:

```
Failure in initial user-supplied objective function evaluation. 
FSOLVE cannot continue.
```

I am a total MATLAB beginner and have no clue where the error lays.

Answer (score 1):

You are not specifying the first parameter of `fsolve` correct.  Taking a look at the documentation is always very useful when you're in doubt about how to call a function.  For `fsolve`, it's here:  http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fsolve.html

In your case, for your `fsolve` statement, you must do this:

```
sol=fsolve(@eqns,guess)
```

`fsolve` expects a function handle to your function that you want to solve, not the actual name of the function itself.